# Doctrine and aliases from the select clause in the where clause

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am using an alias in my select clause (`AVG(u.rating) as avg_rating`) and would then like to add this in my where clause `avg_rating > 3` but when I try and run this query I get a `Unknown column 'u3__1' in 'where clause'`.

Does anyone happen to know how I can get my where clause to see the alias? This alias works in the `orderBy` with no issue, just not the `where`.

**EDIT: (for more details)**

The above was an example, but here is the real rendered SQL, not as simple. My issue is actually with an alias on value with a bunch of conditionals. And the alias I am having trouble with is the generated date which has recurrences and doesn't have to every date field populated. So I am posting a simple SQL query that gives me the same issue.

```
SELECT t.type_id as type_alias, t.* FROM theme as t WHERE t.id > 1 AND type_alias = 3
```

And here is the real query if you are so interested:

```
SELECT t.id AS t__id, t.created_by AS
t__created_by, t.type_id AS
t__type_id, t.url_slug AS t__url_slug,
t.name AS t__name, t.description AS
t__description, t.summary AS
t__summary, t.start_month AS
t__start_month, t.start_day AS
t__start_day, t.start_year AS
t__start_year, t.duration_unit AS
t__duration_unit, t.duration_length AS
t__duration_length, t.is_active AS
t__is_active, t.is_public AS
t__is_public, t.needs_moderation AS
t__needs_moderation, t.recurrence AS
t__recurrence, t.tag_string AS
t__tag_string, t.date_created AS
t__date_created, t.date_updated AS
t__date_updated, AVG(t2.rating) AS
t2__0, IF(t.recurrence = "none",
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, t.start_year), "%m%d%Y"),
(IF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, YEAR(NOW())), "%m%d%Y") >
NOW(),
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, YEAR(NOW())), "%m%d%Y"),
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, (YEAR(NOW())+1)),
"%m%d%Y")))) AS t__1, (COUNT(u.id) +
COUNT(e.id)) AS u__2 FROM theme t LEFT
JOIN theme_rating t2 ON t.id =
t2.theme_id LEFT JOIN
user_saves_themes u ON t.id =
u.theme_id LEFT JOIN event e ON
((e.is_active = 1 AND e.theme_id =
t.id)) WHERE t.id IN ('3', '2', '1')
AND (IF(t.recurrence = "none",
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, t.start_year), "%m%d%Y"),
(IF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, YEAR(NOW())), "%m%d%Y") >
NOW(),
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, YEAR(NOW())), "%m%d%Y"),
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t.start_month,
t.start_day, (YEAR(NOW())+1)),
"%m%d%Y")))) >=
FROM_UNIXTIME(1278001295) AND
t.is_public = ? AND t.is_active = ?)
GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY t__1
```

Comment: Ok, pretty sure this may be due to the SELECT happening after the WHERE, but still not sure how to correct this.

Comment: Can we see the entire *generated* query, please?  (Assuming you're using a query builder instead of writing SQL manually.  Doctrine and all that.)

Comment: Did you try ->where("AVG(u.rating) > 3") ...?

Comment: My current fix that is working is that I have that long series of IFs in a php variable that I just use where I need it. My main issue is that a year is not always required by request of our UX team so I couldn't store it as a date object mixed with recurring events made the condition complex.

Comment: @Tom: My first reply I misread your comment. That is actually what I am doing. But my actual query is quite more complex so I was looking to simplify. It works now, but I just want to make it simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For
>   example, the following query is illegal:

Either you have to add HAVING clause or repeat your alias in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try having instead of where.

Comment: While this might fix the issue under certain circumstances, it's probably not what you want.  `HAVING` runs after `WHERE`, and depending on how many rows are excluded by `WHERE`, performance could suck majorly.

Comment: Yeah, the dynamic query is rather complex and trying the HAVING did not work well.